# Session-id in RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, spring-session

In my `RestController` I'm using

```java
RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getSessionId()
```

to get the session id.
For differet requests (separate endpoints) from the same browser, the session id returned is different.

Is there anything specific that I need to do from UI to have same session ids in the backend for a user's session? (I'm using react-redux for UI)

`application.properties`:

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/some_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = something
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.session.store-type=JDBC
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.timeout.seconds=36000

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

server.port = 8089

logging.level.root=DEBUG

server.ssl.enabled=true

# The format used for the keystore. It could be set to JKS in case it is a JKS file
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/xyz.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=something
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=something
```

Comment: Can you post your application.properties file

Comment: Thanks @Shubh for looking into this, I've edited my question and added `application.properties`

Comment: Here are a few things to check in order to debug this. Is there a session cookie in your browser? What is the cookie domain? Is the session cookie sent with every request to your Spring application? Are you sending any other credentials in the request, for example, basic auth username and password?